# Select row in DataFrame based on values in multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a DataFrame and I'd like to select rows where in one column they have a certain value, AND the row above has a certain value in another column. How do I do this without a for loop?

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4], 'two': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
```

Where I'd like to find the row where `df.one` on that row equals `1`, and `df.two` on the row *above* equals `4`, so in the example row number 4 with values `[1,5]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print df
   one  two
0    1    1
1    2    2
2    3    3
3    4    4
4    1    5
5    2    6
6    3    7
7    4    8

print (df.one == 1) & (df.two.shift() == 4)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
dtype: bool

print df[(df.one == 1) & (df.two.shift() == 4)]
   one  two
4    1    5
```